# Google Vision API returns PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to use the Google Vision API. I'm following [getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/getting-started):

1. I have enabled the Cloud Vision API
2. I have enabled billing
3. I have set up an API key
4. Made base64-encoded data from my image
5. Made JSON file with settings:

   ```
   {
     "requests":[
       {
         "image":{
           "content":"my base64-encoded data"
         },
         "features":[
           {
             "type":"LABEL_DETECTION",
             "maxResults":5
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
6. Sent request with `curl`:

   ```
   $ curl -v -k -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=my_browser_key --data-binary @path_to_file.json
   ```

After that I got response:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Requests from referer \u003cempty\u003e are blocked.",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
          {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
            "links": [
              {
                "description": "Google developer console API key",
                "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/***********/apiui/credential"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

*\u003cempty\u003e means <empty>*

Any ideas? Somebody have the same problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you specify a list of valid referers in the "Accept requests from these HTTP referrers" box shown on that page? If you did you'll probably have to specify one of those:

```
curl --referer https://yourwebsite.com/ ...
```

Or just disable the referer check if you don't need it.

Comment: Hello Matti, thanks for response. No, I didn't specify a list of valid referrers. Do you think that this may be the reason?

Comment: @akomkov The docs seemed to state that if you leave it blank any referer will do, but I guess it's not quite up to date.

Comment: On "that" page? What page? Please indicate where to specify this check.

Comment: Good call, @VisionHive - he means this page in Cloud Console: `https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<project-name>&authuser=<authuser>&organizationId=<organizationId>` (and once I had specified the referer as `https://<projectname>.appspot.com/*` it worked again)